# Combinatorical permutation-cycles problem

Tags: combinatorics

How many permutations $\pi$ $\in$ $Sn$ ($n>2$) where $1$ and $2$ belong to the same cycle?

Here is what I have so far:

First I put $1$ and $2$ in the same cycle and make $j$ elements from the other $(n-2)$ join them in the same cycle: ${n-2 \choose j}$ with $0<j<n-2$

Then I must put the $(n-2-j)$ elements in other cycles. For that I use the Stirling numbers (which garantees that at least 1 element is put in a cycle) in  to distribuite those elements in the $k$ cycles, with $(1<k<j)$:

$S(n-2-j,k)$

My final answer is

$\sum_{j=0}^{\ n-2} {{n-2 \choose j} . \sum_ {k=0}^{\ j} {S(j,k)}}$

Is there something wrong with my resolution or a simpler way to solve it?

Comment: After choosing the $j+2$-cycle, all that's left to construct the full permutation is to figure out where the other $n-j-2$ numbers go, and there are $(n-j-2)!$ ways to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have from first principles the closed form

$$S_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose j} \frac{(j+2)!}{j+2} (n-2-j)!.$$

This is for n $\ge 2$

$$S_n = (n-2)! \sum_{j=0}^{n-2} (j+1) = \frac{1}{2} (n-2)! (n-1) n
= \frac{1}{2} n!.$$

We may think of the permutation in table notation to explain the factor $(n-2-j)!.$ Once we choose the $j$ extra elements for the cycle containing $1$ and $2$, the corresponding $j+2$ pre-image / image pairs are removed from the table. The table now has the remaining $n-2-j$ values in the pre-image and the image and we may permute the values in the image any way we like.

Comment: To elaborate: $(j+2)!/(j+2)$ counts how many $j+2$-cycles there are with the given $j$ chosen numbers alongside $1$ and $2$, and $(n-2-j)!$ is how many permutations of the other $n-2-j$ elements there are (which we multiply by the $j+2$-cycle to get our permutation of the whole $n$-element set). And your second line simplifies the formula by writing the binomial coefficient in terms of factorials and cancelling.

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment, this is indeed how I computed $S_n.$

Comment: @runway44 I might be missing something, why $(n-2-j)!$ is the number of permutations of $(n-j-2)$ elements?

Comment: The number of ways to permute $m$ objects (or put $m$ objects in $m$ bins, one per bin) is $m!$. There are $m$ choices of where to put the first object, $m-1$ choices of where to put the second object, and so on. (This ought to be taught in elementary algebra classes, or at least taught well before discussing permutation cycles in a modern algebra or actual combinatorics class.)

Comment: @runway44 But I can put more than 2 objects in one bin for example:

(3,4,5),(6,7) counting as 2cycles or (3),(4),(5),(6),(7) as 5 but (3,4,5) is equal to (4,5,3) for example, that's what makes this exercise trickier i guess. I don't know if I made my self clear. I don´t know if cyclic-permutations is of well known in general.

Comment: You are misinterpreting what I man by bin. I do not mean cycles. I mean outputs for corresponding inputs. In this context, putting two objects in one bin means two inputs having the same output - you aren't constructing a permutation if you do that.

Comment: For example, suppose $j=1$ and you pick the number $3$ from $\{3,4,\cdots,n\}$, and then you pick one of the two possible $3$-cycles containing $1,2,3$. Then to finish constructing $\pi$, you need to decide on the outputs $\pi(4),\pi(5),\cdots,\pi(n)$ as some permutation of the numbers $4,5,\cdots,n$. There are $n-3$ choices for $\pi(4)$ and $n-4$ choices for $\pi(5)$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a purely combinatorial approach as well. Let $\pi\in S_n$, and let $$\pi=\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_m\tag{1}$$ be its complete representation as a product of cycles, including the $1$-cycles for its fixed points. We can always take $(1)$ to be in the following standard form:

- each cycle is written with its smallest element first, and
- the cycles are arranged in descending order of their smallest elements.

Since $1$ is necessarily the smallest element of the cycle containing it, it must be the first element of $\sigma_m$.

Let $T$ be the set of $\pi\in S_n$ such that $1$ and $2$ are in different cycles of $\pi$. If

$$\pi=\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_m\in T\,,$$

then $2$ is the first element of $\sigma_{m-1}$. Let $\sigma'$ be the concatenation $\sigma_m\sigma_{m-1}$. That is, if $\sigma_{m-1}=(2\ldots s_k)$ and $\sigma_m=(1\ldots t_\ell)$, then $\sigma'=(1\ldots t_\ell 2\ldots s_k)$. (Note that this is **not** the product of $\sigma_m$ and $\sigma_{m-1}$.) Let $\hat\pi=\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{m-2}\sigma$. Then $\hat\sigma\in S_n\setminus T$ and is written in the standard form $(1)$.

This transformation is invertible. If $\pi=\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_m\in S_n\setminus T$ is in standard form, then $\sigma_m$ has the form $(1\ldots t_\ell 2\ldots s_k)$. Let $\sigma_{m+1}'=(1\ldots t_\ell)$ and $\sigma_m'=(2\ldots s_k)$; then $\pi'=\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{m-1}\sigma_m'\sigma_{m+1}'\in T$ is in the standard form $(1)$, and $\widehat{\pi'}=\pi$. Thus,

$$|S_n\setminus T|=|T|=\frac12|S_n|=\frac{n!}2\,.$$